# How to solve "Call to undefined function AES_ENCRYPT" MySQL data array

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I am trying to add AES_ENCRYPT to Joomla component.

Original MySQL is this (without encryption):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// datetime
$date_publish = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
// Insert columns.
$columns = array('category_name', 'category_description', 'status', 'created_date');
$values = array(
    $db->quote($name), 
    $db->quote($description), 
    $db->quote($status) , 
    $db->quote($date_publish)
);

// Prepare the insert query.
$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__group_categories'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

I have modified it with **AES_ENCRYPT**:

```
$values = array(
    AES_ENCRYPT($db->quote($name), '12345'), 
    $db->quote($description), 
    $db->quote($status) , 
    $db->quote($date_publish)
);
```

But when run the code: It was given this error: (Fatal error: Call to undefined function AES_ENCRYPT())

can someone please help me, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you..

```
$values = array(
    "AES_ENCRYPT(".$db->quote($name).", '12345')", 
    $db->quote($description), 
    $db->quote($status) , 
    $db->quote($date_publish)
);
```

As joomla is considering AES_ENCRYPT(); as joomla or php function, so keeping as string might solve your problem.